# Why would you choose the Method of Frobenius over a Power Series solution to solve a DE?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I'm trying to determine where it would be more appropriate to use one or the other.

To further clarify:
Where would it make more sense to use:

$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x-x_0)^{n+r}$ instead of $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x-x_0)^{n}$

Comment: You need to give us some definitions, since some people would say they are equivalent.

Comment: Have you heard of ordinary and singular points of differential equations?

Comment: Yes.  Regular and irregular singular points, and ordinary points.